# Angular filtering object based on array of strings

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'd like to be able to filter an entire object based on an array of strings. Currently the default filter will search an entire object based on a single string value, but not with an array of strings.

[current jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtbyrd21/bbhxmLwj/4/)

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div> 
        <ul determine-filtering> 
            <li get-filter-tag active-state="false" tag="{{button}}" 
            ng-repeat="button in buttons">
                {{button}}
            </li>
        </ul>

        <hr/>
         <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="item in content | filter:filterArray">
                {{item.data.headline}}
            </li>
        </ul>    

    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
var testapp = angular.module('testapp', [])


.filter('inArray', function($filter){
    return function(list, arrayFilter){
        if(arrayFilter.length > 0){
            console.log(arrayFilter);
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem) != -1;
            });
        }else{
            return $filter("filter")(list, function(listItem){
                return arrayFilter.indexOf(listItem) == -1;
            });
        }
    };
})


.directive('getFilterTag', function () {
        return {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function(){
                    var tag = attrs.tag;
                    var filterArray = scope.filterArray;
                    if(filterArray.indexOf(tag) === -1){
                        scope.filterArray.push(tag);
                    }else{
                        filterArray.splice(filterArray.indexOf(tag), 1);
                    }
                    scope.$apply();

                });
            }
        };
    })

.directive('activeState', function () {
        return {
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function(){
                    attrs.activeState = !attrs.activeState;
                    if(!attrs.activeState){
                        $(this).addClass('active');
                    }else{
                         $(this).removeClass('active');
                    };
                });

            }
        };
    })

.controller('myController', function($scope){
    $scope.filterArray = [];
    $scope.buttons = ['corn', 'vegetable', 'onion'];
    $scope.content = [
        {

            "type": [
                "recipe"
            ],
            "data": {
                "prepTimeInMinutes": 10,
                "serves": "6 to 8",
                "headline": "North Carolina Piedmont Slaw",
                "ingredients": [
                    {
                        "item": "medium head cabbage",
                        "quantity": {
                            "number": 1
                        },
                        "notes": "cored and chopped (5 to 6 cups)"
                    },
                    {
                        "unit": "cup",
                        "item": "ketchup",
                        "quantity": {
                            "number": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "unit": "tbsp.",
                        "item": "sugar",
                        "quantity": {
                            "number": 3
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "unit": "tbsp.",
                        "item": "apple cider vinegar",
                        "quantity": {
                            "number": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "unit": "tsp.",
                        "item": "kosher salt",
                        "quantity": {
                            "fraction": {
                                "display": "½",
                                "denominator": 2,
                                "numerator": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "unit": "tsp.",
                        "item": "black pepper",
                        "quantity": {
                            "fraction": {
                                "display": "½",
                                "denominator": 2,
                                "numerator": 1
                            }
                        },
                        "notes": "freshly ground"
                    },
                    {
                        "item": "Generous dash hot sauce, such as Texas Pete Hot Sauce or Tabasco brand"
                    }
                ],
                "description": "",
                "cookTimeInMinutes": 180,
                "categories": {
                    "Dish Type": [
                        "Side"
                    ],
                    "Main Ingredient": [
                        "Vegetable"
                    ]
                },
                "cookingDirections": [
                    {
                        "step": "Place the cabbage in a large bowl."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": "Combine the ketchup, sugar, vinegar, salt, pepper and hot sauce in a liquid measuring cup. Pour over the cabbage and toss to coat thoroughly. Cover and refrigerate for at least 3 hours, and preferably overnight, before serving."
                    },
                    {
                        "step": "Serve on top of the pulled pork"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }



    ]










} );
```

I have a custom filter which worked with arrays, but not with arrays with nested objects. What is the best approach to do this kind of filtering? Is there anything the $filter service already provides for searching based on arrays?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to filter an object based on an array of strings (matching the objects properties) I would look into [lodash#omit](https://lodash.com/docs#omit).

Usage:

```
var obj = { a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c' };
var arr = ['a', 'c'];

_.omit(obj, arr); // { b: 'b' }
```

I'm not sure whether omit supports deep/nested objects. If not, you could compose it with an iterator to determine whether the given key of an object is an object itself and run another omit on that.